# Nivo Slider not working with wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

All of a sudden the nivo slider on one of our clients websites is not showing up at all: www.bedehouse.org

I have tried all sorts but cannot see why its stopped all of a sudden? We have not done any updates to wordpress or any of its plugins recently.

I can see using chromes "inpect element" feature that there is an error: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).nivoSlider is not a function" but have no idea what it means.

Any helps or pointers in the right direction would be massively helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading two versions of jQuery. One is the copy WordPress is loading and the second is another.

Both are different versions (WP is loading 1.8.3 and you're loading 1.8.2). WordPress loads jQuery in noconflict mode and does not allow the use of the $ shortcut.

Remove the jQuery 1.8.2 call that you made and change all instances of $ to jQuery and try it.

Comment: I'm not sure how but since posting here the slider seems to have come back on its own accord before I got a chance to try your suggestion!

Comment: I've removed the jQuery call from functions.php but not sure where to change the $ instances?

Comment: Everywhere. Because of how WordPress loads the jQuery library, it does not include the $ shortcut.

Comment: For the life of me I cannot find which file has the call to the nivo slider script in it: $(window).load(function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({

Comment: I wouldn't know where that is without seeing your template files. However, you will need to change EVERY instance of $ to 'jQuery' because, as I explained earlier, WordPress loads jQuery in noconflict mode which means you lose the capability of using the $ shortcut.

You need to look through your template files and find where that code is. Probably something like front-page.php but, again, I cannot know for sure without looking at the files myself.

Comment: Also, I revisited the site just now and you still have 2 calls to jQuery in there. One is calling the local copy from WordPress, 1.11.3 (Line 46) and again on line 61 you're calling v1.8.2 from code.jquery.org.

Comment: Ok I have removed the second call to jQuery but still cannot find how the Nivo Slider custom script is injected. I've gone through every single .php template file and cannot locate the call to it anywhere. Is there a way I can search for the code in the files?

Comment: Finally found it! Was in theme options. Have changed to "jQuery" but still not working :(